# No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!

Tags: arch-linux, boot, usb-drive, iso, syslinux

I have copied, as usual, the iso into usb disk (/dev/sdc):

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=archlinux-2014.08.01-dual.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

But when I boot to my new PC, it shows:

```
ISOLINUX 6.03 6.03-pre18* EHDD Copyright (C) 1994-2014 H. Peter Anvin et al
No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!
```

I have also tried for `archlinux-2014.05.01-dual.iso` and `manjaro-xfce-0.8.10-x86_64.iso`, but it shows the same result.

I have tried to rename `syslinux` folder, `syslinux.bin`, `syslinux.cfg` to `isolinux`, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329704/)  using `isomaster`, then `dd` back to usb, but it won't boot at all.

Note: this never happened on my previous PC.

Motherboard: MSI H81M-E33

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you looked at your USB boot options in the BIOS/UEFI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a problem in the USB stick. Some sticks won't boot directly as if they were a CD drive. Try the manual formatting strategy, as described on: [USB Flash Installation Media](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_Flash_Installation_Media#In_GNU.2FLinux_2)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it's usb disk's fault, when I copy the iso file into the usb disk, the md5sum is different from the source (harddisk)..

USB Disk: Kingston 8GB --> it's fake Kingston